# Formik setFormValues not working inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, npm, use-effect, formik, maskedinput

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import MaskedInput from "react-text-mask";

const phoneNumberMask = [ "(", /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ")", " ", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, "-", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/ ];

export default () => {

  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFormValues({ phone: '9178889999' });
    }, 1000)
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ phone: '9134445555' }}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        enableReinitialize
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            handleChange,
            handleSubmit,
          } = props;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Field name="phone">
                {
                  ({ field }) => <MaskedInput
                    {...field}
                    type="text"
                    mask={phoneNumberMask}
                    placeholder="Enter your phone number"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className="text-input"
                  />
                }
              </Field>
              <button type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

where the `MaskedInput` gets initially populated with value: `9134445555` using format: `(913) 444-5555`.

**My problem is:** The call to: `setFormValues(...)` doesn't work from inside: `useEffect` after a timeout of `1 s (1000 ms)`.

**My Goals**

1. The `MaskedInput` gets populated with second value: `9178889999` after `1 s`.
2. The `MaskedInput` shows the second value with proper format: `(917) 888-9999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to achieve both goals on the code above:

1. Change: `initialValues={{ phone: '9134445555' }}` to: `initialValues={ formValues || { phone: '9134445555' } }`
2. On the `package.json` change: `"react-text-mask": "^5.4.3"` to `"react-text-mask": "5.4.1"`.

If we use latest version as of today: `5.4.3` then the pattern won't be applied on value change. This issue happens from version: `5.4.2`. That issue doesn't exist on version: `5.4.1`, though. That's why I use that version.

By the way this library seems to be not maintained since: `July 2018`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simple, you didn't wire `formValues` to your `initialValues`.

This leads to another issue, your mask is not updating properly : [React Form value not updating when toggling InputMask mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326345/react-form-value-not-updating-when-toggling-inputmask-mask).

Comment: that's a good point. I expanded your explanation on my answer. Thank you!